# How to load Bio2Vec in gensim?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, gensim

I have been trying to use Bio2Vec for a medical word embedding project using gensim. I have downloaded "BioWordVec_PubMed_MIMICIII_d200.bin" from the web however, i am unable to load it. This is the error message:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'º\x16O/'"

I understand that there is some invalid character in the bin file because of which I am not able to load this. However, I am not sure how to correct it.

I am not able to open the bin file and edit anything. Can someone help?

This is the code that I am using:

```py
model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(
    datapath('BioWordVec_PubMed_MIMICIII_d200.bin'),
    encoding='windows-1252', binary=True)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I edited your question, (1) so it is better readable, (2) that it is clear that you are using gensim. Without this piece of information, no one would be able to help you.

Comment: Are you sure of the encoding argument that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the `BioWordVec_PubMed_MIMICIII_d200.bin` file, and were any instructions supplied along with it?

I believe that project might use FastText, and thus its output files are not plain sets-of-word-vectors that could be loaded with `load_word2vec_format()`.

You might have better luck trying the `load_facebook_model()` or `load_facebook_vectors()` methods, as described at https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html. But of course the actual source of the file will be the best authority on how to re-load it.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply.

I downloaded it from GitHub and the code that I supplied earlier was the instruction provided to load Bio2Vec.

I don't want to use FastText as the text that I have is Medical History of an Individual and I am afraid that FastText could not give me good results. I chose to use Bio2Vec as it is very domain specific.

Do you suggest any other wordembedding models that can be used for medical records????

Comment: An exact link to where you got it would be more helpful than "downloaded it from Github". When I find projects called "Bio2Vec", they seem to be FastText-based, so their `.bin` files could not possibly be loaded with the code you've tried – you'd have to use FastText-compatible code to load them. So you'd be using FastText-based vectors if you use Bio2Vec. Your other option is to train your own vectors from your own data, which should work well, perhaps even better than anyone else's vectors, if you have a lot of data.

Comment: I really appreciate your response... Yes, I was not able to load it in fastext for some reason. However, I downloaded a different medical embedding and was able to load it in Word2Vec. Thank you for your assistance. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import gensim
# https://github.com/ncbi-nlp/BioSentVec
# Embeddings using PubMed and the clinical notes from MIMIC-III Clinical Database

word2vec = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(
     'BioWordVec_PubMed_MIMICIII_d200.vec.bin',
      binary=True,
      # limit=None, # this fuckin thing has 4 billion tokens (4E9)
      limit=int(4E7) # faster load if you limit to most frequent terms
)
print('Using %s word vectors.' % len(word2vec.wv.vocab))
```